# How to stop php curl from rewriting cookies

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

My code:

```
<?php

function access_page($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}                  

?>
```

Every time I run this function, my cookie.txt file gets deleted and rewritten with new cookies even when the cookies don't colide.
For example:

```
access_page("http://examplepage.com/session","");
access_page("http://examplepage.com/login","username=123&password=123");
```

I want this to write both session and login cookies in my cookie.txt file however the first request gets rewritten by the second one even though the cookies are different.
**How can I keep both of these cookies in the cookie jar?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) manual page

> 'w' Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file **and truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.

(bold emphasis mine).

So these lines are actually removing all of the content, so remove these lines...

```
$fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
```